# Give standard input to program through files and take standard output to a file

Tags: java, input

How to give standard input to java program through files and take standard output to a file?

i don't want to make the program to make use of file input methods. program should take input from standard input like BufferedReader, but at runtime input should be taken from a text file and not through keyboard. Similiarly, the output generated by the program should be redirected to a text file.
I think there is some option associated with the javac/java command. But i don't exactly know. Can someone guide me how to do this? I am using jdk1.7 for windows 7, 32 bit system

Comment: Please learn how to use capital letters.  1) Don't SHOUT at us. 2) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: OK, but could you please answer my question too?

Comment: you mean something like `java myprogram < input_file > output_file` ?

Comment: ya mee confused too......

Comment: moderators just make sure the question make sense not that they answer.

Comment: use java properties -D (fileName&Location) option to java command and access the properties in code.

Comment: you mean you want to redirect your program using `textfile` not through program?...

Comment: i want to execute my program like an online judge does. There is an input file from which the program takes the input. and output is stored in a file

Comment: @user2916888 try my previous comment (Evgeniy has put an answer for the same). Is that what you want?

Comment: VusP, yes i want to do it like that

Comment: I tried that:
e.g. : 
java Test In.txt Out.txt
but it did not work

Comment: @user2916888 When you say it is not working you also need to show how you did it, what you expected and what you got. You used those angle brackets? (redirection operators) ?

Comment: sorry, it is working. i was making mistake. Thanks VusP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use OS redirection operators

```
java Test < inputFile > outputFile
```

then this

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        for(int i; (i = System.in.read()) != -1;) {
            System.out.write((byte)i);
        }
    }
}
```

will copy from inputFile to outputFile

Comment: maybe i am making some mistake. but its not working

Comment: I tested it before posting, worked OK. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class test.Test

Comment: and thanks for answering but i worked out how to do it. :)

Comment: To recap, it appears that the original problem was that you were not calling "javac" or you were forgetting to set the right classpath.

Comment: yes. the edited version is working

Comment: I see. Remove package test from Test.java. Recompile. Run java Test ... instead of java test.Test ... in the same folder where Test.class is